# Is there any way to monkey patch builtin parentheses [], (), {} behaviour? (in python 3 code, without modifying C/interpreter)

Tags: python, built-in, monkeypatching

I am just checking where is the limit of changing python using python (without modifying interpreter and/or C code).

I know that I can basically monkey patch every builtin function like this:

```
import builtins
int(1)
# 1

def new_int(number):
    return number + 1

builtins.int = new_int
int(1)
# 2
```

I know I can turn python classes upside down using special methods like `__new__`, `__get__` [etc.](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=453682&seqNum=6) and that I can overload any operator.

but is there any way to monkey patch parentheses? so that instead of creating list, python will do something else with elements between `[...]` like creating tuple.

```
# normal
old = [1,2,3,4]
print(old)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
type(old)
# <class 'list'>

# some strange code that monkeypatches [] so that instead of list, it creates tuple
def monkey_patch_list(values):
    return tuple(values)
[] = monkey_patch_list  # of course it is wrong

# new
new = [1,2,3,4]
print(new)
# (1, 2, 3, 4)
type(old)
# <class 'tuple'>
```

Probably there is no way to do it just in python but maybe somewhere hidden in python code there is a definition of handling [] so that I can mess it up. If there is anyone crazy like me and knows how to do it I will appreciate help.

Disclaimer:
Don't worry just for fun, thanks ;)

Comment: There should be no such method in pure Python. They are regarded as literal in Python, and will be directly translated into corresponding bytecodes. For example, `[...]` corresponds to `BUILD_LIST`, `(...)` corresponds to `BUILD_TUPLE`, or `LOAD_CONST` without building. I don't think you can do it unless you modify the bytecode implementation or the interpreter itself.

Comment: You would need to manipulate how Python interprets the source file.  You may wish to reference and extend the [quasiquotes](https://quasiquotes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to implement what you want.

Comment: Just as a curiosity: the R programming language *does* allow this, since virtually all punctuation is implemented as function calls, and these functions can be overridden. The only exceptions are `;` (the statement separator) and `|>` (the pipe operator).

Comment: @MechanicPig today I was on pycon22pl and is just so happened that someone had a part of speech about it - the same info and examples as yours so thanks! It seems there is no way to monkeypatch it, but the answer below someone suggested editing ast, it is kinda hack but still clever solution.

Comment: @metatoaster this is interesting, will check this out thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as a function decorator as long as the lists to be replaced as tuples are defined in a function.

To do that, use `ast.NodeTransformer` to replace any `ast.List` node with an equivalent `ast.Tuple` node in the function's AST:

```
import ast
import inspect
from textwrap import dedent

class ForceTuples(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_List(self, node):
        return ast.Tuple(**vars(node))

    # remove 'force_tuples' from the function's decorator list to avoid re-decorating during exec
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        node.decorator_list = [
            decorator for decorator in node.decorator_list
            if not isinstance(decorator, ast.Name) or decorator.id != 'force_tuples'
        ]
        self.generic_visit(node)
        return node

def force_tuples(func):
    tree = ForceTuples().visit(ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func))))
    ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
    scope = {}
    exec(compile(tree, inspect.getfile(func), 'exec'), func.__globals__, scope)
    return scope[func.__name__]
```

so that:

```
@force_tuples
def foo():
    bar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(bar)
    print(type(bar))

foo()
```

outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MellowLinearSystemsanalysis

Comment: Nice, this is extremely clever solution! Never thought of just editing ast, so many new possibilities. Thank you!